# VLC recording rtsp stream

Tags: stream, record, rtsp, vlc, transcode

I have a problem with recording rtsp stream with VLC player. Actually my method works in MacOS X, but doesn't in Windows. Command line:

```
vlc -vvv rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.151/live/h264/ --sout="#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vfilter=canvas{width=800,height=600}}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=C:\123.mp4}"
```

On MacOS it works fine, but under Windows it creates unreadable file. MediaInfo output:

```
General
Complete name                            : C:\123.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 1.08 MiB
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like your destination URL is not correct. Try this:

```
vlc -vvv rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.151/live/h264/ --sout="#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vfilter=canvas{width=800,height=600}}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=C:\\123.mp4}"
```

Answer (score 6):

For Linux users, `ffmpeg` alone works straight away.

If you want to watch the stream while recording, write to a `.mkv` instead of a `.mp4`.

This example will overwrite the file `video.mp4` in your home folder without asking  due to the `-y` param, and the original codecs are kept.

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.42.1/live -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y ~/video.mp4
```

---

NB: This example url is for an *[Ambarella Xiaomi Mijia 4K camera](https://github.com/Theliel/Xiaomi-Mijia-4K)*, like many wifi ip cameras, you have to **activate the stream via telnet first**, for this particular model the command to be sent before reading the stream via rtsp://:

```
echo '{"msg_id":257,"token":0}' | telnet 192.168.42.1 7878
```