# How to capture frame continuously during camera streaming

Tags: camera, streaming, rtsp

I'm using https://github.com/pedroSG94/RTSP-Server library module for streaming and I want to capture frames continuously.

Comment: You can use VLC to record the stream - see example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22320286/334402

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` is best for recording streams

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://xx:yy@x.x.x.x:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y x.mp4
```

Here:

-i: The RTSP URL that needs to be recorded

-vcodec: The original video codec

-acodec: The original audio codec

copy: Create a copy of the stream

x.mp4: The name of the file to be created.